# Change behaviour of Chrome omnibox so it doesn't force google search when typing 'google'

Tags: google-chrome

When I want to search for something related to Google using chrome, I start typing 'google' in the omnibox. Immediately, Chrome changes this to "Search Google (Default)" to do a Google search.

[image: Search Google (Default)]

But this is not what I want. I just want to make 'google' part of the query.

How do I change or switch off this behaviour in Chrome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click within the address bar and select "edit search engines".  For the google (default) search string change the text trigger string (the second column) to something else, like a string of gibberish.  This is now still the default search engine, so it will be used for any text entered, but it won't trigger upon entering the word 'google'.